# How to override/prevent sqlalchemy from ever using floating point type?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've been using pandas to transform raw file data and import into a database. Often times we use large integers as primary keys. When using pandas `to_sql` function without explicitly specifying column types, it will sometimes automatically assign large integers as float (rather than bigint).

As you can imagine, much hair was lost when we realized our selects and joins weren't working.

Of course, we can go through and via trial-error manually assign problem columns as bigint, but we'd rather outright disable float altogether and instead force bigint since we work with an extremely large amount of tables, and sometimes an extremely large amount of columns that we can't spend time individually fact-checking. We basically never want a float type in any table definition, ever.

Any way to override floating point type (either in pandas, sqlalchemy, or numpy) as bigint?

---

ie:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

e = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host')

columns = ['foo', 'bar']
data = [
    [123456789, 'one'],
    [234567890, 'two'],
    [345678901, 'three']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df.to_sql('table', e, flavor='mysql', schema='schema', if_exists='replace')
```

Unfortunately, this code does not reproduce the effect. It committed as bigint. It happens when loading data from certain csv or xls files, it happens when doing a transfer from one MySQL database to another (latin1) which one would assume to be an isometric copy.

There's nothing to the code at all, it's just:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

e = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM source_schema.source_table;', e)
df.to_sql('target_table', e, flavor='mysql', schema='target_schema')
```

Creating a testfile.csv:

```
thing1,thing2
123456789,foo
234567890,bar
345678901,baz
```

didn't reproduce the effect either. I know for a fact it happens with data from [NPPES Dissemination](http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html), perhaps it has to do with the encoding? I have to convert the files from WIN-1252 to UTF-8 in order for MySQL to even accept them.

Comment: A small example that reproduces this behavior would be helpful. Seeing some code and output, even if we have to assume some things about a database and connection that we can't reproduce, would go a long way.

Comment: Does it only happen when you involve ODBC in the mix? If you check out the ODBC type conversions, you can see that almost all int types are converted to plain SQL_INTEGER, which will be a 32-bit *signed* integer. You have to do something special (with `bigint`) to get SQL_BIGINT. I would imagine that any straightforward mapping, even from `numpy.int64` that is done by pandas, pyodbc, or sqlalchemy, will perhaps check if the default mapping would result in a precision loss (it should) and then fall back on some heuristic for preventing precision loss, which appears to be just picking float.

Comment: Here's a [link about the ODBC type conversions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-reference-datatypes.html).

Comment: @Mr.F I'm at a loss. I can't reproduce this. It only happens with ODBC, and apparently only when I execute a perfect rain dance. The first time we noticed it was from a 1:1 transfer from a db sitting on a remote web host to our local server (remote had numbers stored as VARCHAR... don't ask, I didn't do it), the other time it was from importing NPPES data.

Comment: @CodeShaman If this is really happening (int column converted to a float), then this should be a bug. But, can you check with a dataframe where this does happen, show the output of `df.dtypes` is (so, ti check it are certainly ints in pandas (maybe in the import goes something wrong)), and secondly, can you show the output `pd.io.sql.get_schema(df, 'test_name', con=e)`? Also, what version of pandas are you using?